# Meteor-kitchen server-side rendering

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to make meteor-kitchen to render on the server side?

Currently it renders all via javascript, but I'm also planning on building a REST API, so I need server-side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish server side rendering with meteorhacks:ssr + iron:router. You create an iron route on the server side and then render blaze templates. Here is an example route.

```
this.route('home', {
    where: 'server,
    path: '/',
    action: function() {
        var templateData = {};
        var html = SSR.render('templateName', templateData);
        this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        this.response.write(html);
        this.response.end();
    }
});
```

I'm using this method to serve up static pages for SEO on https://gameraven.com/.

Comment: thank you Derrick for the reply, but can you expand on this answer, on where this piece of code goes?

Comment: That code can go in server/main.js
I would suggest you read through the documentation on both packages.
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router and
https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr